# axios response data to pre-select on multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, multi-select

Im using the popular plugin  for multiselect [shentao/vue-multiselect](https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect)

```
<multiselect v-model="test.selectedTags" 
    :options="options" 
    :multiple="true" 
    :clear-on-select="false" 
    :hide-selected="true" 
    :preserve-search="true" placeholder="Pick some" label="name" track-by="name" :preselect-first="true">
</multiselect>
```

On my code im using axios request to fetch user id and name to be pre-selected by the multi-select

```
editUrl: function(id){
    let vm = this;
    axios.get('api/urls/' + id)
    .then( response => {
    vm.test.selectedTags = response.data.data.users.map(user => ({  name:user.name, id: user.id }))
         })
    .catch( error => {
         console.log(error);
     });
     },
 }
```

and the response looks like this

```
selectedTags:Array[2]
    0:Object
        id:3
        name:"asdaa"
    1:Object
        id:4
        name:"atetest"
```

Now, I successfully got the result and pre-select the data in multi-select
[image]

However when i click the "x" to remove, it doesnt remove the selected data and no errors has been shown. How to fix this? TIA

This is what my options object looks like

```
options:Array[2]
    0:Object
        id:4
        name:"atetest"
    1:Object
        id:3
        name:"asdaa"
```

Test object

```
test:Object
    created_at:"2018-09-07 15:58:51"
    description:"server5"
    id:9
    latest_url_status:Object
    list_status:1
    selectedTags:Array[2]
        0:Object
           id:3
           name:"asdaa"
        1:Object
            id:4
            name:"atetest"
    updated_at:"2018-09-07 16:48:34"
    url:"https://httpstat.us/200"
    users:Array[2]
```

return data

```
export default {    
        data(){
            return {
                test:{
                    url: "",
                    selectedTags:[]
                },
                urls:{},
                users:{},
                contacts: [],
                monitorModal:false,
                result: '',
                pagination: {},
                loading: true,
                edit:false,
                urlChecked: {},
                logsModal: false,
                logsData:{},

                //mulltiselect
                options: []
            }
        },
    }
```

Comment: try `v-model="selectvalue"` and `:options="test.selectedTags"` , the `selectvalue` add it to your data object as follow `selectvalue:''`

Comment: i tried it it is not pre-selecting the value

Comment: so set ` v-model="test.selectedTags"` and keep `:options="test.selectedTags"`

Comment: now i have already the pre-selected values but when i click the "X" it doesnt remove the option

Comment: check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hLexkyz/641/)

Comment: no it is still not working i cant remvoe the option even if i click the X

Comment: on your example you cant search the option

Comment: i dont get it my response data looks like this https://jsfiddle.net/0hLexkyz/660/ but is not working

Comment: what couldn't you get ?

Comment: i cant remove option when I hit the X

Comment: in the jsfiddle that you provide it works fine