# preselect select options vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Im using the popular multiselect for vue js [shentao/multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/)

```
<multiselect v-model="test.selectedTags" :options="options" :multiple="true" :clear-on-select="false" 
:hide-selected="true" :preserve-search="true" placeholder="Pick some" label="name" track-by="name">
</multiselect>
```

and when i preselect the options manually like this

```
test:{
    url: "",
    selectedTags:[{id:3, name:'asdaa'}]
},
options: []
```

i get the correct result and i can remove the option on the select when i click the "X"
[image]

My options response looks like this

```
options:Array[2]
    0:Object
        id:4
        name:"atetest"
    1:Object
        id:3
        name:"asdaa"
```

however when i fetch from my backend and put it on `test.selectedTags` the response will look like this same format (array of objects)

```
//THIS IS THE OPTIONS THAT WILL BE AVAILABLE ON SELECT
selectedTags:Array[2]
    0:Object
        id:3
        name:"asdaa"
    1:Object
        id:4
        name:"atetest"
```

[image]

but when i click the "X" i cant remove the option and no errors has been shown? can somebody help TIA

**EDIT**

but when i comment the variable from response i can now remove the option when i click the "X" however i cant get the other data that i needed

```
editUrl: function(id){
    let vm = this;
    axios.get('api/urls/' + id)
    .then( response => {
         vm.edit = true;
         //vm.test = response.data.data;
         vm.test.selectedTags = response.data.data.users.map(user => ({ id:user.id, name:user.name }))
         vm.monitorModal = true;
     })
     .catch( error => {
         console.log(error);
      });
},
```

Comment: How is this different to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243026/axios-response-data-to-pre-select-on-multiselect)?

Comment: i can now remove the option when i click the "X" however i cant get the other data that i needed check the edit

Comment: Please update your old question since it has no answers yet.